# Оправдано ли применение Visual Basic .NET для автоматизации производства?

Tags: .net, visual-basic

Оправдано ли применение VB.NET для написания ПО, автоматизирующего работу производства, когда есть C++ и C#?
Предполагается работа с SQL и очень много - по периферийным устройствам (сканеры штрих-кода, принтеры наклеек и т.д и т.п.)
В чем плюсы и минусы, и каковы области применения VB вообще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Вы работаете с .NET, не очень важно, на каком языке Вы пишете. Семантические конструкции будут идентичны в разных .NET-языках, только записываться они будут по-разному.

Несколько особо стоит Managed C++. Он позволяет использовать .NET и stl одновременно. Но нам при работе с периферийными устройствами это не потребовалось - хватило библиотеки POS for .NET, всё писали на C#.

Так что если вы привыкли писать на VB.NET - никаких проблем. Наоборот, переходить на другие языки было бы нецелесообразно, лишние затраты на обучение.